# Find all pairs of consecutive numbers in BST

Tags: binary-search-tree

I need to write a code that will find all pairs of consecutive numbers in BST.

For example: let's take the BST  T with key 9, T.left.key = 8, T.right.key = 19. There is only one pair - (8, 9).

The naive solution that I thought about is to do any traversal (pre, in, post) on the BST and for each node to find its successor and predecessor, and if one or two of them are consecutive to the node - we'll print them. But the problem is that it'll will the **O(n^2)**, because we have n nodes and for each one of them we use function that takes **O(h)**, that in the worst case h ~ n.

Second solution is to copy all the elements to an array, and to find the consecutive numbers in the array. Here we use **O(n)** additional space, but the runtime is better - **O(n)**.

Can you help me to find an efficient algorithm to do it? I'm trying to think about algorithm that don't use additional space, and its runtime is better than **O(n^2)**

*The required output is the number of those pairs (No need to print the pairs).

*any 2 consecutive integers in the BST is a pair.

*The BST containts only integers.

Thank you!

Comment: Define *find* in "*find all pairs*" - what is the required output? And what precisely does "*pairs of consecutive numbers*" mean? Any 2 consecutive integers used as keys? What is a valid relation between the 2 nodes?

Comment: Edited. The required output is the number of those pairs (No need to print the pairs). And yes, any 2 consecutive integers in the BST.

Comment: So what is the output if not printed? It's not clear why a simple inorder traversal isn't enough (just keep track of previous value and test with current)

Comment: The output is the number of pairs. In the example at the first post the output should be 1 (because there is only one pair).
And what do you mean to keep track of the previous value?

Comment: An inorder solution, especially with a Tree with threaded pointers, can easily scan through the tree in linear time.  (Threaded trees allow you to iterate over a tree without recursion).  Thus, you can iterate over the tree as if you were scanning an array.  Here's a link for threaded binary trees:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree

Comment: Just like your proposed 2nd solution, but instead of filing an array for later traversal, do the counting as you traverse the tree. Just remember what value the previous node had to do that

Comment: @rts1, Thank you for your comment. I can't use threaded tree because it is a standard BST (If a node has no children he points to NULL).
@ Amit, I'll try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just do an inorder traversal and count pairs on the fly? You'll need a global variable to keep track of the last number, and you'll need to initialize it to something which is *not* one less than the first number (e.g. the root of the tree). I mean:

```
// Last item
int last;

// Recursive function for in-order traversal
int countPairs (whichever_type treeRoot)
{
  int r = 0; // Return value

  if (treeRoot.leftChild != null)
    r = r + countPairs (treeRoot.leftChild);

  if (treeRoot.value == last + 1)
    r = r + 1;

  last = treeRoot.value;

  if (treeRoot.rightChild != null)
    r = r + countPairs (treeRoot.rightChild);

  return r; // Edit 2016-03-02: This line was missing
}

// Main function
main (whichever_type treeRoot)
{
  int r;

  if (treeRoot == null)
    r = 0;
  else
  {
    last = treeRoot.value; // to make sure this is not one less than the lowest element
    r = countPairs (treeRoot);
  }

  // Done. Now the variable r contains the result
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! yes it's exactly what I wanted to reach.
Is there a way without global variable? I thought to pass 'last' as argument, but I don't think that it'll works.

Comment: If using an object-oriented language, this can be an attribute. If using C or similar, it could be a static local variable, except that you'll have trouble initializing it. Also, it could be a variable declared in main() and you could pass a pointer to the recursive function.